# iOS6 Simulator MKMapKit "Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios-simulator, mapkit

Running my app with the iOS6 simulator I am getting the following printed in the XCode console prior to `viewDidLoad` getting called:

> Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework

Has anyone else encountered this, and if so have you found a reason why? My guess is that it has to do with the iOS6 Apple Maps, but who knows!

EDIT

I should add that I don't get this warning in the iOS 5.1 simulator.

Comment: i also have this:
Couldn't find hybrid.styleproto in framework
It might be related to the visual style of the map. But why?

Comment: Somehow when I added a button on top of the map I had this problem. I remove it and add it again the problem was gone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a way to consistently reproduce this.

First, the culprit is a set of files in the Cache folder for your simulator. Go to your Application Support folder for the iPhone Simulator:

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[6.0 and above]/Library`

Then look inside of your `Caches/GeoServices/Resources`

You'll see some `.styleproto` files in there. These files are only created when MapKit is **first used** in a simulator. It may also happen on the device, but I haven't confirmed it.

If you want to test this, make sure you have the `.styleproto` files, then re-launch your app, and you won't see the warning again when accessing the maps.

Remove the `GeoServices` cache folder, quit and restart the simulator (and your app), and there is the warning!

Comment: But where can we find the .styleproto files ?

Comment: In the folder I specified above. Can you find `iPhone Simulator` in your `~/Library/Application Support` folder?

Comment: Now I can find the Caches/GeoServices/Resources folder of the simulator.  But there isn't any .styleproto files ...  Please help.

Comment: Hmm... why do you need these files? Anyway... I ran the build in Maps app and they showed up there.

Comment: The only file in my ~/GeoServices/Resources is attributionBadge-1.cn.png

Comment: I just wish to get ride of the "Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework" warning.  Otherwise the map seems to be behaving ok although I haven't added any coding to the map yet.

Comment: hello abellina, i also faced the same error, and i am able to find those files also but my question is why we need to keep those files before run the project. Is there any other way to solve it ? because first i reset my simulator and then run my project... and it generate error but for the 2nd time ,, it runs...

Answer (score 2):

I solved by adjusting the MKMapView in my view controller to iPhone 5 new size, now I got no warning message.

Comment: So you used to have prior to this a set width and height? My map isn't full screen. I also can't seem to replicate this anymore.

Comment: I set the mapview with flexible with, height and margin in interface builder, the classic UINavigationController + MKMapView

Answer (score 2):

mmm...I had de same problem...I think the problem could be the 6.0 Simulator; if I set the Deployment Target to 5.1 and run the app using the 5.1 Simulator and uncheck the Autolayout check-box, I didn't have any problem, but if I use the 6.0 Simulator when I run the app, the map doesn't appear, and the message "Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework" is printed in Xcode console...

Comment: I can't replicate this. I set the deployment target to 6.0 and run it in the 6.0 simulator, with autolayout, but that didn't cause the log message.

Answer (score 0):

Please set your GPS settings active otherwise this error may occur again. Also,it is advisable to set the frame for the iPhone 5  .

Answer (score 0):

I just turned on my wireless on device and this warning disappear and my map comes visible.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Shows User Location]
This is old, but for anyone who comes across this thread like I did, it may also be that the option "Shows User Location" on the map view object was not checked. This was my issue and not about cache above, although I got the exact same error in console. I didn't even try the cache fix from the answer above, all I did was check that option and voila.

Answer (score -1):

If your iOS simulator's GPS setting is none, you will get this waring. Just change iOS simulator's GPS setting to "Apple Stores" or other, it will gone.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't replicate this. I set it to none, and the only error I get is when the map can't find the user, not the styleproto error. I haven't seen this in a while.