# Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework. iOS 6.0 on 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, ios6

Its showing up with no graphics because of this, and this just happened. Everything was working fine until this new update came out. I created a new project to test if I messed up the original one, but still same problem. I also repeated the steps but I keep finding the source of the problem to be in the actual Map view in the objects folder for you to add to the storyboard. It does not seem to be in the Mapkits framework, but I may be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626536/ios6-simulator-mkmapkit-couldnt-find-default-styleproto-in-framework

Answer (score 0):

I just ran up against the same problem. It appears to be a problem with setting the mapType property of a MKMapView. In my code I commented out this set and everything ran fine.