# Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Its showing up with no graphics because of this, and this just happened. Everything was working fine until this new update came out. I created a new project to test if I messed up the original one, but still same problem. I also repeated the steps but I keep finding the source of the problem to be in the actual Map view in the objects folder for you to add to the storyboard. It does not seem to be in the Mapkits framework, but I may be wrong.

This seems because of the switch for apple, now that they dont have google supporting their maps, and I can not find a single thing online about the solution to this.

I just want to display a mapview and show two points with directions. Is there a way to do this with the new apple update?

Comment: possible duplicate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626536/ios6-simulator-mkmapkit-couldnt-find-default-styleproto-in-framework