# Map View Bug In Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, maps, ios6-maps

I was creating ScreenShots in my upcoming App and now the iOS Simulator isn't loading the maps. It was 10 mins earlier now its just a black yellow page. I am connected to the internet (How could I post this Question). I tested the app on my iPhone 4 and its loading fine. What is the issue?

[image]

Update: I am getting this Error: `Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework` in NSLog

Comment: Could we see some relevant code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS6 Simulator MKMapKit "Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626536/ios6-simulator-mkmapkit-couldnt-find-default-styleproto-in-framework)

Comment: I am going to submit a bug to apple.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to set map type and also check framework integration . Like as...3

```
mapViewObj.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
```

mapViewObj is object of MKMapView.