# MKMapView warning : "default.styleproto"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, mkmapview

What is "default.styleproto" ?  I searched the web and there seems to be quite a lot who are having the same warning :

```
Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework
```

It should be related to iOS6 MKMapView. Cannot find any satisfactory answer to this yet.  Wish to know if there are any official documentation about *.styleproto files.

Despite having this warning, the map seems to be behaving ok.  But really wish to know more about this "default.styleproto" warning and how to get rid of it.

Hope somebody knowledgable could help ...

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered. Please make sure that no one has asked the same question as you before posting one. The link to the answered question is:
[iOS6 Simulator MKMapKit "Couldn't find default.styleproto in framework"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626536/ios6-simulator-mkmapkit-couldnt-find-default-styleproto-in-framework)
Judging form the name of the file, I believe it may have some thing to do with the protocol for the maps image? I have never had an apple device, but it seems likely to me.
I cannot provide any more help on this. Hopefully I have helped at least a little.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the post, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem or explain what is default.styleproto.